# Dump only a portion of memory in VS 2005

Tags: c++, c, debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

Does any one know if there is a way to dump only a chunk of memory to disk using VS?  Basically, I want to give it an address and a length, and have it write the memory to disk.  That way I can do a binary diff.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean 'Is there a way to dump only a chunk'? Why cant you use standard file IO/pointer techniques?

Comment: I could write code to do it for me, but I'd rather use the IDE if possible.  I could also use printf to debug, but I'd rather use the watch window.

Comment: Like... while debugging?

Answer (score 3):

I'm kind of surprised VS won't let you do that from the Memory dump window...

You might be able to get what you want (or close to it) with the VS command window:

```
>Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput c:\temp\testdump.log /overwrite
>Debug.ListMemory /Count:16 0x00444B20
0x00444B20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 13 00 12 00 86 07 19 00  ................
>Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput /off
```

If you're willing to use WinDBG, (or ntsd/cdb) you can use the `.writemem` debugger command to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only save a complete binary minidump. However, you can use the Debug Memory window and copy/paste to a text file to do memory diffs.

Comment: Yeah, the trouble is that the memory window won't show me enough at one time.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this I have tried in VS 2008, but I believe VS 2005 should allow the same:

If the memory is a string (if it doesn't contain zero bytes), you can put the following into a watch window: `(unsigned char*)(ptr),1024` to see 1kB in the text visualizer. However, this stops at zero bytes, so if you have binary data, this won't work.